# How to return a value from custom function in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress

I've been struggling with returning a value from my custom function due to the fact that I'm dealing with a promise.

Here's my code:

**This is my custom function:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add("myFunction", () => {
   cy.get('#someID').then($container) => {
      const isHidden = $container().children('div:nth-child(3)').is(':hidden');
      console.log(isHidden); // This returns either true or false and that is good  
      return isHidden; // this returns $chainer but I want to return either true or false 
   }

});
```

**Here is my test suite:**

```
context('some description', () => {
  before(function(){
      const result = cy.myFunction();
      console.log(result); // This is $chainer, but I want to get the value of true or false from isHidden variable 
  });

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can't return values like that in cypress. Did you try using aliases?

Answer (score 6):

I am doing this with `cy.wrap` (see https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap/#Syntax) which returns a Cypress.Chainable that allows you to use `then` with the result.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('myFunction', () => {
    return cy.wrap('myResult');
})

cy.myFunction.then((text) => {
    console.log(text); // myResult
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, however, my code never goes inside of the "then" section.